# How to remove a single outline block in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

When using outlining in Visual Studio ("Edit" tab -> "Outlining") one can add an outline block for collapsing, or to stop outlining altogether. But how do I remove a single outline block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your cursor anywhere within the outlined block and hold down **Ctrl** while pressing **M**, then **U** on your keyboard.

The alternative is to click **Edit -> Outlining -> Stop hiding current**.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that was for un-collapsing an outline.

Comment: Nope, you would do that with Ctrl + M + O (think O for "open"). ;)

Answer (score -1):

A region is defined in code by the #region tag

```
#region

// code here

#endregion
```

simply edit the code and remove the beginning and ending tags to remove a region.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about "outlining", because while editing a CSS file (in Visual Web Developer) there's no in-built support for regions. I Changed the wording of the question now to avoid confusion.